# FindallElements using className does not work but using the same code with xpath works

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, getelementsbyclassname

For practice I was working on code and faced a very strange problem. I am trying to find the list of all elements using className. When I check the list size it returned me 0 but the same class when used with xpath works. My code is below

```
    WebDriver driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.localbanya.com/home/search?searchKeyword=dove");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ms-choice']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ms-drop       bottom']//li[4]/label")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".proceed-button.button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
     List<WebElement> prList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='prName']"));

    // This particular code does not work  but same class name used above works 
    //----Interesting not working
    //List<WebElement> prList = driver.findElements(By.className(".prName"));

    System.out.println(prList.size());
    for (WebElement web : prList)
    {
        System.out.println(web.getText());
    }

    //driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> prList = driver.findElements(By.className("prName"));
```

It will work, no need to use `.` while you are using `By.className`. `.` is required when you use css selector.